# Windows 7, connecting to Samba shares

Tags: windows-7, samba

How can I connect to a Samba share with authentication using Windows 7?

We have a bunch of Linux, HP-UX and AIX servers on our network with folders shared using Samba.  These are not connected to our Active Directory or anything, we just type a user name and password when we connect to them.  They still all work fine from Windows XP, but we've upgraded a couple of machines to Windows 7 and they can't access the shares.  You get prompted for a password but it says "The specified network password is incorrect" (it's not).

Comment: See also http://serverfault.com/questions/91797/windows7-the-specified-network-password-is-not-correct-when-the-password-is

Answer (score 24, accepted):

1. Run: gpedit.msc
2. Find:

   Console Root -> Local Computer Policy -> Computer Configuration -> Windows Settings -> -> Security Settings -> Local Policies ->Security Options

   When you're there change the following policies
3. Microsoft network client: Send unencrypted password to third-party SMB server: Switch it to "Enabled".
4. Network security: LAN Manager authentication level: 
   Select the option: Send LM & NTLM - use NTLMv2 session security if negotiated.

Comment: Thanks, this solves the problem.  It sounds like we should probably be upgrading samba on all our servers too, but that will take a while...

Comment: doesn't work for me >:(

Comment: @ Cy. Instead of running gpedit.msc and doing all that navigation, secpol.msc takes you directly to your security settings. Everything else is correct otherwise..

Comment: Unless you're running an old version of Samba none of this should be  necessary. You're best off upgrading Samba.

Comment: @user168261: I'm running latest version of Samba.  #4 works (and is needed).  #3 is unnecessary (with later Samba versions).

Comment: I am running Windows 8 and this solution did not work for me.

Comment: On Windows 7 x64 Enterprise - A reboot was not needed.- Samba Version 3.0.33-3.40.el5_10

Comment: I don't have gpedit.msc

Comment: `Windows + R > secpol.msc` is the choice to edit policies... in Windows 7 Ultimate, if you try to add an Snap-in via `mmc` in order to administrate local policies, it does not allow you to change policies, even though you are an Administrator.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. This did the job for me:

[Get Vista and Samba to work | TechRepublic](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/get-vista-and-samba-to-work/6353849)

> 1. Open the Run command and type "secpol.msc".
> 2. Press "continue" when prompted by Vista.
> 3. Click on "Local Policies" --> "Security Options"
> 4. Navigate to the policy "Network Security: LAN Manager authentication level" and open it.
> 5. By default Windows Vista sets the policy to "NTVLM2 responses only". Change this to "LM and NTLM – use NTLMV2 session security if
>      negotiated".

Comment: +100 if I could!  Been trying to get this working for over a day.

Comment: For Windows 7, set "Network security: LAN Manager authentication level" --> Send NTLMv2 response only

Answer (score 3):

If you're running an old version of Samba, it's possible that you're run into [this problem](http://www.arkko.com/linux/vistanas.html).  Here is some [further discussion](http://www.geektieguy.com/2006/09/18/how-to-connect-to-older-samba-server-versions-using-vista-rc1/). Basically, Windows Vista and 7 disable an old and insecure method of authentication which Samba was using by default.  Tweaking the registry setting as described in the article should get it working.  Ideally, of course, you would upgrade Samba to a new version, but that might not be possible at the moment.

If this doesn't work, could you post the version of Samba that you're running?

Comment: I did not have a LmCompatibilityLevel key on my Win7 machine.  I don't know if creating the key would have worked? The gpedit solution worked for me anyway.

Comment: What version of Samba is required?  Is it a samba configuration issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue. When I try to connect I get `0x80004005` permission error:

[image]

While I do:

- Change Network security: LAN Manager Authentication Level to “Send LM & NTLM responses”
- Change Minimum Session Security for NTLM SSP to disable “Require 128-bit encryption” into “No Minimum Security”.
- Uninistalling [KB2536276](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2536276).

another thing stop from done is:

- activate `Client for Microsoft Networks` in my WiFi dangle `Network panel`.

Enabling `File and printer sharing for Microsoft Networks` in  `Network panel` allow me access to Win7 shared folders.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9548125/173149