# Why samba based clients have troubles with Windows 7 shares?

Tags: windows-7, samba

I have a number of Samba-based devices in my home (a NAS, a DVB-T decoder, a media center, an Ubuntu PC) and they all have some troubles with my Windows 7 based systems (desktop + 2 notebooks). They often don't even see the computer on the network. I tried enabling and disabling almost every setting (firewall, encryption key size, password based sharing, some registry keys to enable anonymous as everyone) but without real effects.

Is this a known issue? How can I solve or workaround it?

Answer (score 0):

On the Win7 machine run secpol.msc

Under Microsoft Network Client set "Send unencrypted password to third-party SMB server" to "Enabled".

Under Network security set "LAN Manager authentication level" to "Send LM & NTLM - use NTLMv2 session security if negotiated"

That seems to solve most access to Samba share problems on Win7 machines.  I've had the same problem at work twice.  Those steps solved it.  I wish I could claim all the credit, but I originally found the resolution [here](https://superuser.com/questions/115337/windows-7-connecting-to-samba-shares?rq=1).  If you're running on an Active Directory network you may have a rights management issue.