# Windows 7 Home and Samba 2 share

Tags: windows-7, samba

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows 7, connecting to Samba shares](https://superuser.com/questions/115337/windows-7-connecting-to-samba-shares)

I can't get Windows 7 Home to connect to a Samba 2 share?

I keep seeing articles that suggest using `'secpol.msc`', or 'gpedit' which I think isn't on the home version, as I cant find it.

I can connect on MacOS so I'm guessing the this is done to the Windows side of things.

The error I get is
`"A remote procedure call (RPC) protocol error occurred."`

Comment: What error are you getting? Please be more specific.

Comment: @studiohack yeah I read this one, win 7 home doesn't seem to have gpedit.msc as well

Comment: that's correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this post (for what it's worth) by komickaze @ http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/75-63-windows-samba-issue:

> I had a similar problem when trying to connect Windows 7 Home Premium and Windows 7 Ultimate to a Mac OS 10.3.9 Server. I made the following change with the Local Security Policy on Ultimate and tested it successfully while watching the registry for changes. I found the following REG_DWORD values were changed:
>
> HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\LmCompatibilityLevel
>   HKLM\System\ControlSet001\Control\Lsa\LmCompatibilityLevel
>
> After further testing, I found these to be the values and coresponding settings:

```
0) Send LM & NTLM responses
1) Send LM & NTLM - use NTLMv2 session security if negotiated
2) Send NTLM response only
3) Send NTLMv2 response only
4) Send NTLMv2 response only. Refuse LM
5) Send NTLMv2 response only. Refuse LM & NTLM
```

> I created the LmCompatibilityLevel setting on my Home Premium machine with a value of 1 (http://www.builderau.com.au/blogs/codemonkeybusiness/viewblogpost.htm?p=339270746) and was finally able to connect to the 10.3.9 Server.

Located about halfway down the page, use <kbd>CRTL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and search for a keyword in komickaze's post.