# Samba share not accessible from Win 7 - tried advice on superuser

Tags: windows-7, network-shares, samba

I have an old Red Hat Linux box that I use, amongst other things, to run Samba.  My Vista and remaining Win XP PC can access the p/w-protected Samba shares.

I just set up a new Windows 7 64-bit Pro PC.  Attempts to access the Samba shares by clicking on the Linux box's icon in 'Network' from this machine gave a `Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.` message when I gave the correct credentials.

So I followed the suggestions in [Windows 7, connecting to Samba shares](https://superuser.com/q/115337) (also checked [here](http://www.arkko.com/linux/vistanas.html) but found LmCompatibilityLevel was already 1).

This got me a little further.  If click on the Linux box's icon in 'Network' from this machine I now see icons for the shared directories.  But when I click on one of these, I get `\\LX\share is not accessible. You might not have permission...` etc.

I tried making the Win 7 password the same as my Samba p/w (the user name was already the same).  Same result.

The Linux box does part of what I need for ecommerce - the in-house part, it's not accessible to the Internet.  As my Linux Fu is weak, I have to avoid changes to the Linux box, so I'm hoping someone can tell me what to do to Win 7 to make it behave like XP and Vista when accessing this share.

Help please!?

Thanks

---

Thanks for replying @Randolph.  I had set 'Network security: LAN Manager authentication level' to `Send LM & NTLM - use NTLMv2 session security if negotiated` based on the advice in [Windows 7, connecting to Samba shares](https://superuser.com/questions/115337/windows-7-connecting-to-samba-shares) and had restarted the machine, but that didn't work for me.

I'll try playing with other Network security values.

---

I have now tried the following:

> Network security: Allow Local System to use computer identity for
>   NTLM: changed from Not Defined to "Enabled".

- Restarted machine

Still says "\LX\share is not accessible. You might not have permission..." etc.

> Network security: Restrict NTLM: Add remote server exceptions for NTLM
>   Authentication (added LX)

- Restarted machine

Still says "\LX\share is not accessible. You might not have permission..." etc.

I can't see any other Network security settings that might affect this.  Any other ideas please?

Thanks

Roy

Comment: Have you restarted the windows machine after you changed the samba share password?

Comment: On the Windows box can you search the Security event log (`eventvwr.exe`) for failed logon attempts and provide that as a part of your question?  I'll be able to offer better advice if I can see the event details.  Have you tried authenticating with `Win7HostName\username`?

Comment: Are you prompted for credentials when opening a remote directory? make sure you put the remote hostname as the domain (e.g. `redhat\redhat_user` and the password you created for the red_hat user account). Also, can you post up your smb.conf and highlight the share you've tested that isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look on the Windows 7 box in `Local Security Policy`, under `Local Policies` > `Security Options`. There's a series of NTLM-related policies to play with.

The `LmCompatibility` option you've already changed in the registry is governed by the policy

```
Network security: LAN Manager authentication level
```

which in your case should be set to "Send LM & NTLM - use NTLMv2 session security if negotiated".

You will need to restart the Windows machine for this to take effect.

Comment: Still unable to access from Win 7 though.  See question, which I have added to.    Roy

Answer (score 0):

Control Panel - Administrative Tools - Local Security Policy

Local Policies - Security Options

Network security: LAN Manager authentication level Send LM & NTLM responses

Minimum session security for NTLM SSP Disable Require 128-bit encryption

Answer (score 0):

Check your `smb.conf` file under `[global]` and see if the following is in that section:

`ntlm auth = no
lanman auth = no
client ntlmv2 auth = yes`