# What is a straight forward way of sharing files over the LAN between Ubuntu and Windows

Tags: windows-7, linux, ubuntu, lan, samba

I have Ubuntu desktop in an old PC and I bought a new PC, pre-loaded with Windows 7. These are connected in a LAN. I am able to ssh to Ubuntu from Windows fine through putty. Over the years of use of the old Ubuntu PC has accumulated lots of files.

Instead of copying them over to the new Windows PC I want to mount my home directory in Ubuntu to Windows. One option I can think of is doing a samba share.

Samba seems too complicated for me. I read the configuration and it has tons of configuration options. Is there a easier and straight forward way? Or can someone point to quick samba config for achieving this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows 7, connecting to Samba shares](http://superuser.com/questions/115337/windows-7-connecting-to-samba-shares)

Comment: @ashwin. Do you have Samba set up and running already or are you asking for an alternative/setup instructions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There ways other than Samba, but they are likely more complicated, not less. Plus, when you install Samba, the default configuration already provides shares for accessing home folders.

Check out this answer for the details : https://askubuntu.com/a/165596