# Cannot find share on Ubuntu from Windows 8 using samba

Tags: ubuntu, samba, file-sharing

I have properly set up a share using samba (as best I can tell because I can access the share with my Macbook by navigating to smb://192.168.1.14/share).

How do I connect to this same share called "share" from my Windows 8 desktop?

I've tried typing into my Windows Explorer address bar:

`\\[servername]\share`
servername == the name of the ubuntu server

`\\192.168.1.14\share`

Windows says it "cannot access" the address so this indicates Windows isn't being denied, its just not finding it at all. There is no promt for credentials as I was given on my OS X machine.

---

Notes:

I have not set `security = user` or any other security settings outside `workgroup = WORKGROUP` in `/ect/samba/smb.conf`

apache2 has been installed on the server and I can access the initial page by navigating to 192.168.1.14 in a browser.

`sudo iptables -L` results in:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

I have also changed the security setting noted on this question: [Windows 7, connecting to Samba shares](https://superuser.com/questions/115337/windows-7-connecting-to-samba-shares)

Comment: If you ping the Ubuntu box, do you get a response? CMD - 'ping ...'

Comment: I am able to ping that IP address (deleted previous incorrect comment).